# PMOS turn on and turn off condition

Tags: pmos

I am planning to use the FDC6312P (PMOS) in my circuit and want to know the turn on and turn off condition for the PMOS. I looked at the datasheet to find the turn on and turn off condition but too much information is hurting my beginners brain. Could someone please help out here? The datasheet can be found here. [FDC6312P datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdc6312p-d.pdf)

This is how I have configured the PMOS in my circuit.
[image: FDC6312P datasheet]

Comment: When using a MOSFET as a switch, you want the Vgs listed to achieve the rated RDson. You do not want the Vgsth because that is when the MOSFET just barely starts to conduct.

Comment: how are your drain and source connected?